# Scala: numerical operations on Option type

Tags: scala, option-type

At Devoxx conference this year, Dick Wall gave a [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhXUlPmLLts) on designs and patterns in Scala programming; and the first part was supposed to be brief highlights on the basics. At 1:09:35, he wrote the following function:

```
def safeDiv(a: Int, b: Int): Option[Int] = if (b == 0) None else Some(a / b)
```

which returns an compile error [good]. My question is since this is a fairly common scenario to encounter: how can I do integer operations * / + - on the returned value of

```
safeDiv(6, 2) // Some(2)
```

something like

```
safeDiv(6, 2) * 6 // 18 [error]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot multiply Option on Int, you definitely should multiply value of Option like so:

```
 saveDiv(6, 2).map (_ * 6)  // Returns Option[Int]
```

or you can use "Pimp My Library" pattern to define method '*' on Option of Int:

```
 class PimpedOption(oi:Option[Int]) { 
   def *(i:Int) = oi.map(_*i)
 }

 implicit def instance(oi:Option[Int]) = new PimpedOption(oi)
```

Then you can do:

```
 saveDiv(6, 2) * 6 // Gives Option[Int]
```

Comment: thanks @Nyavro, although I got a warning that said I needed to import scala.language.implicitConversions, your solution worked. I would like to know, however, if there's a simpler way of doing this, other than defining a method on Option[Int] type. I was thinking of way to convert Option to Int, is there such a thing in Scala?

Comment: @Nyavro, you can also just make an `implicit class ...`, then you don't need the separate `implicit def`.  @AbdulelahAlJeffery, have you had a look at `getOrElse()`?

Comment: Actually you cannot directly convert Option[Int] to Int, becaluse there possible None value.

Comment: Option has method 'get' but I would not recommend to use it - you will have to check if Option has value first. Instead use map, getOrElse, foreach and other functional-style methods

Comment: @jwvh I'm considering the option type because of it's safer than getOrElse method, which I think is more for setting default values

Comment: @AbdulelahAlJeffery, your comments are contradictory. First you say you are "thinking of way to convert Option to Int" which is what `getOrElse()` does in a safer way than you'd have by using `get()`.  Then you say "I'm considering the option type because of it's safer ...".  So you want to keep the `Option` and **not** convert it to `Int`.  I agree that is the safer way to go.  Let the data remain as an `Option` for as long as possible.

Comment: @jwvh I have no idea why on stackoverflow you can't update your comment after 5 minutes, I actually wanted to update the first comment I made about the conversion and ask for a way to convert, cast, or coerce the Option type into Int, just to perform the numerical operation and to convert it entirely to Int, but yes you're right it seems like what I'm asking for is not clear!

Answer (score 2):

Do it in the map block

```
saveDiv(6, 2).map(_ * 6)
```